# Removing android phone app

Tags: android, android-source

I have source the code of android 2.1, and I want to remove phone app from it. But I am not able to remove it. At list first I want to remove it from launcher that it should not be visible in  launcher but in manifest file of Phone app I can not able to find launcher category. I don't know what to do?

Comment: which IDE are you using for developing android apps?! Is it Eclipse?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove all

```
<category andorid:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

in packages/apps/**Contacts**/AndroidManifest.xml, I think it will work fine.

Or try to remove Contacts.apk (but this may not work because you may get crash again.)

Comment: I already mentioned  category launcher is not available in Phone app. I don't no how still we can able to view phone app in launcher

Comment: Yes, not in Phone app. It is in Contacts app.

Comment: Saying precisely, the target activity is "DialtactsActivity" in Contacts app.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the phone app completely from your phone, then it's as easy as deleting `/system/app/Phone.apk`. If you want to compile a framework that does not *show* the phone app in the launcher, then you will need to modify the launcher, not the phone app.

Comment: if i remove Phone.apk system is crashing. I have already tried

Comment: @HellBoy How does it crash? What does the logcat say? It's probably because some other app depends on it. For example, in the Captivate, the Camera app will crash if you remove Email.apk...

Comment: Yes you are right. On phone app other app are Dependant as well some system dependency is also there( I am not sure.) It very hard to resolve this problem.

Comment: Not that hard: read the logcat and find out why an app depends on it. Can you remove the second app also? Or perhaps you'll want to modify the code so it does not depend anymore on it (adding a try/catch block or modifying the exception handling should suffice)